# Как сделать шрифт толще 900 с помощью css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я хочу сделать свой шрифт очень толстым из-за цвета фона изображения моих друзей, которое находится в заголовке веб-сайта. Я нашел это в Интернете, но, к сожалению, он не работает. есть ли другой способ сделать это?

```css
h1{
  text-shadow: 1px 0 #888888;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>MAKE IT BOLD</h1>
```

Это решение не работает и сохраняет его примерно той же стандартной толщины, что и у меня.

Есть ли способ сделать шрифт толще 900?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [how to make font thicker then 900 using css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66537690/7394871) от участника  [@Gianluca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14376347/gianluca).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66537690/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Используйте  [text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)

```css
.box {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
.th {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px;
  text-stroke: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD</div>
<div class="box th">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Или много раз `text-shadow`:

```css
.box {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
.th {
  text-shadow:0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px,0 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD</div>
<div class="box th">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537745/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

*Обдумайте использование SVG фильтров*

```css
h1{
  text-shadow: 1px 0 #888888;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-weight:bold;
  filter:url(#f1)
}
```

```html
<h1>MAKE IT BOLD</h1>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="0" height="0"  >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f1">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
        
    </feGaussianBlur>   
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 

</svg>
```

Такая же комбинация фильтров, но вместо оператора `atop` используется оператор `xor`

```css
h1{
  text-shadow: 1px 0 #888888;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-weight:bold;
  filter:url(#f1)
}
```

```html
<h1>MAKE IT BOLD</h1>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="0" height="0"  >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f1">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
        
    </feGaussianBlur>   
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 24 1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538500/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

А почему бы не использовать `drop-shadow filter`?

Но забудьте об этом ответе, `text-stroke` - это лучший способ.

```css
h1{
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
  font-weight:bold;
  filter:
    drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #000)
    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 #000)
    drop-shadow(1px -1px 0 #000)
    drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0 #000)
}
```

```html
<h1>NOW THAT'S BOLD</h1>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537947/7394871) от участника  [@Creaforge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3013279/creaforge).</sub>